# Windows context menu directory\background AppliesTo

Tags: windows, shell, menu, directory

I am currently making context menu entries for a program I am creating.
The program will only work inside a designated folder. I would therefore like to have my context menu also only be present inside that folder.

For the buttons appearing when you right click files or folders. I have added a string called "AppliesTo", and it works, the context entries only appear while inside the designated folder.

However when clicking on the background of a folder (the entries located in Directory\Background) the AppliesTo does not work, the entries do not appear anywhere.

Is there a way of using Applies to for Directory\Background? Or do I have to create a shellextension to get the desired behaviour?